# Entity Framework Many to Many Insert

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I have a `Product` model class that has a `virtual Keywords` property (`ICollection Keyword`) and a `Keyword` model class that has a `virtual Products` property (`ICollection Product`).

The table structure this created is what I was looking for: 3 tables, `Product`, `Keyword`, and `ProductKeyword` (many to many relationship table).

In my `create` method I am trying to create a record in the `Product` table, a record in the `Keyword` table (if the given keyword doesn't already exist) and then add the relationships in the `ProductKeyword` table. The `Product` insert works as well as the `Keyword` insert, but I cannot get the `ProductKeyword` table insert to work.

Here's the code:

```
if (!ModelState.IsValid)
{
    return View(product);
}

product.AddedDate = DateTime.Now;

foreach (string keyword in splitter.Split().Distinct())
{
    var existingKeyword = db.Keywords.FirstOrDefault(k => k.Content == keyword);
    if (existingKeyword == null)
    {
        existingKeyword = db.Keywords.Add(new Keyword() { Content = keyword });
    }

    //product.Keywords.Add(existingKeyword) or existingKeyword.Products.Add(product) both fail here with a null reference exception
}

db.Products.Add(product);
db.SaveChanges();

return RedirectToAction("Index");
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `Include` to load the relationships.

```
 db.Keywords.Include("Products").FirstOrDefault(k => k.Content == keyword)
```

Comment: That worked!  Thanks. The only other change I needed to make was to also initialize existingKeyword.Products = new List<Product> if it is null.